# How was this summation performed?

Tags: bayesian-network

Say I have the following simple Bayesian network involving 3 r.v.s A, B, and C:

$$
A \rightarrow C \rightarrow B
$$

I am trying to prove that A and B are conditionally independent given by marginalizing out C and seeing if I get out $p(a, b) = p(a)p(b)$ in

$$
p(a, b) = p(a) \sum_{c} p(b|c)p(c|a)
$$

However, I am not sure how to simplify $\sum_{c} p(b|c)p(c|a)$. How do the $c$s go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being conditionally independent means the following:

$$p(a,b|c) = p(a|c)p(b|c)$$

that is, the value of c is the evidence. That was your problem. You were trying to prove the wrong property. Given $c$, the sum reduces to $p(b|c)$.

Comment: Ah thanks. If the sum is $c$, why does the sum reduce to $p(b|c)$?

Comment: because the value of c is known, is given, so there is only one term to consider

Comment: Oh, because $p(c|a)$ sums out to 1?

Comment: No, because c is given, is no longer a random variable, but has a definite value. Say you are working with words (this would correspond to the trigram model), then p(b|c) is the probability of having the word "b" after the word "c". In general you would need to sum over c, that is, the whole vocabulary. p(a,b) is the probability of having the word "a" at the 1st position and the word "b" at the 3rd, considering all possible c's. But now, the 2nd word is given, so you do not sum over c, because that word is known. p(a,b|c) gives you the probabilities of all combinations (a,b) compatible with c.